# Using own employee table to manage users in mvc using roles and identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, database-first

I am currently new to ASP .Net MVC and I'm working on a project. I already created my database  which has a Employees table (which will consist of the users of the system) where I would want to manage all employees. I know mvc comes with a built in functionality that creates the roles and users table for you from code migration. How would I be able to implement that with my own database? Another problem, I tried creating a default and script the tables, added them to my database but the primary keys which is of type int doesn't match that of the id in the dbo.aspnetusers table that was created.

Can anyone assist me?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is bit unclear. but from what i have understood so far i can say that if your application is to be used internally, then you should consider using windows authentication and implement your own role provider. 
Additionally you will need to provide more detail on what your are trying to achieve. this sounds to me like more of a design question rather than implementation question.

Comment: I authenticate the users with active directory, It works fine, but in terms of authorization I am at a lost as to what to do. How can I manage the users if I have a database table already created?

Comment: you will need to implement custom role provider on top of a mapping table which will hold mapping between roles and windows identities. you do not need tables created by asp net scripts. just create a "roles" table and another table called "user roles" (mapping table). you can create these table manually.